# free php software development project management software needed

Tags: php, desktop-application

I am currently working on a big project (development) and I am looking for software where I can add the pending tasks and the progress of those tasks and time left till target project completion.

I need something that's simple to use.

Any suggestions anyone please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). It is easy to use, free and there are a lot of plugins available, for example an integration into eclipse or SVN! You can plan every task with time left etc. of course.

Comment: I assume OP is looking for a PHP based app for that, like [Arbit Tracker](http://arbitracker.org/).